# Error on load "libmysqlclient.18" - gem mysql2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rubygems, bundle, mysql2

After I executed `bundle`, I don't get to use rails nor rake.
If I execute `rails s` or `rake db:migrate` or `bundle exec rackup`, I have this error:

```
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `require': dlopen(/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/mysql2-0.3.20/lib/mysql2/mysql2.bundle, 9): Library not loaded: /usr/local/lib/libmysqlclient.18.dylib (LoadError)
Referenced from: /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/mysql2-0.3.20/lib/mysql2/mysql2.bundle
Reason: image not found - /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/mysql2-0.3.20/lib/mysql2/mysql2.bundle
```

Sorry not break the code above (I don't like this scroll), but I did not want to hinder the understanding of the problem.

```
OS: Mac OS X Yosemite - 10.10.3
Ruby -v: ruby 2.0.0p481 (2014-05-08 revision 45883) [universal.x86_64-darwin14]
Rails -v: Rails 4.2.1
Mysql2 version: mysql2 (0.4.3, 0.3.20, 0.3.18)
```

I tried (separated commands in different momments):

```
sudo gem update mysql2
sudo ln -s /usr/local/mysql/lib/libmysqlclient.18.dylib /usr/lib/libmysqlclient.18.dylib
```

Other info:

The command:

`otool -L /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/mysql2-0.3.18/lib/mysql2/mysql2.bundle`

return

```
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/mysql2-0.3.18/lib/mysql2/mysql2.bundle:
    /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/libruby.2.0.0.dylib (compatibility version 2.0.0, current version 2.0.0)
    /usr/local/lib/libmysqlclient.18.dylib (compatibility version 18.0.0, current version 18.0.0)
    /usr/lib/libssl.0.9.8.dylib (compatibility version 0.9.8, current version 0.9.8)
    /usr/lib/libcrypto.0.9.8.dylib (compatibility version 0.9.8, current version 0.9.8)
    /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1213.0.0)
    /usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 228.0.0)
```

PS: `bundle` works fine, no errors

Tks

Comment: do you have database created in mysql which you use in database.yml and correct username and password

Comment: Not the ideal solution but I have experienced similar errors to this with the latest versions of the `mysql2` gem.  In my case I just restricted the version in `Gemfile` with:  `'mysql2', '~> 0.3.18'`.

Comment: Are using Ubuntu or linux OS?

Comment: @uzaif Yes, this project is older and it works before. But when I needed to install new gems with bundle, this problem happens...

Comment: @SeanHuber I change the version but the same problem happens

Comment: @DineshSaini I am using Mac OS X Yosemite - 10.10.3.

Comment: @SeanHuber I insisted on your solution and I did it works, thanks! I posted the solution here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**[SOLVED]**

@SeanHuber suggested that I use `mysql2 -v 0.3.18`

I uninstalled the version `0.3.20` MySQL2:

```
sudo gem uninstall mysql2 -v 0.3.20
```

After that I installed the version `0.3.18`:

```
sudo gem install mysql2 -v '0.3.18'
```

And in my Gemfile:

```
gem 'mysql2', '~> 0.3.18'
```

After that, the bundle works.
I need to update some gems, as devise.
Consequence, I did the ruby upgrade to 2.2.3.

Now, all works.

Conclusion:
`mysql2 -v 0.3.20` is bad.

Thanks @SeanHuber to show me the way.

Comment: Awesome!  We should still figure out what it is about the new version that is causing the issue, but I'm glad you have a work-around for the time being.

Answer (score 0):

Please follow the following steps as you are missing some required libraries required to make database adpater connection:

```
sudo apt-get install libmysql-ruby libmysqlclient-dev
sudo apt-get install libmysqlclient-dev
gem uninstall mysql
bundle install
```

Comment: Hey, thanks your answer. I cant to do this, because I am using Mac OS X, not linux...